# Update table in mysql using elementor form

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, elementor

I want to update a table on phpmyadmin using elementor form in wordpress,

but i couldn't make any progress, since the record still not updated

this function should be included in *functions.php* file.

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $ajax_handler ) {

//make sure its our form
$form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'login_form' );
// Replace MY_FORM_NAME with the name you gave your form
if ( 'login_form' !== $form_name ) {
    return;
}
$raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
$fields = [];
foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
    $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
}

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update( ‘LC_USERS’, array( ‘solde’ => ‘1555’ ), array( ‘email’ => $fields['email'] ) );

$ajax_handler->add_response_data( true, $output );
```

}, 10, 2);

Answer (score 1):

Do not write 'form name' here

```
   $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'login_form' );
```

Keep it like

```
   $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );
```

Rest all is well!